# How to create a new variable in a data.frame based on a condition?

Tags: r, dataframe

Assume we have a dataframe

```
x   y
1   1
2   4 
4   5
```

how can you add a new variable to the dataframe such that if x is less than or equal to 1 it returns "good" if x is between 3 and 5 it returns "bad" else returns "fair"

```
x   y  w
1   1  "good"
2   2   "fair"
5   5   "bad"
```

Applied the method shown by ocram., however this one here does not work.

```
d1 <- c("e", "c", "a")
d2 <- c("e", "a", "b")

w <- ifelse(d1 == "e" & (d2=="e"), 1, ifelse((d1 == "a") & (d2 =="b"), 2, ifelse(d1 == "e"),3,99))
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Your last code is not working since you've messed up parentheses; it should be always `ifelse(cond,ifTrue,ifFalse)`, never `ifelse(cond) ifTrue, ifFalse`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One obvious and straightforward possibility is to use "if-else conditions". In that example

```
x <- c(1, 2, 4)
y <- c(1, 4, 5)
w <- ifelse(x <= 1, "good", ifelse((x >= 3) & (x <= 5), "bad", "fair"))
data.frame(x, y, w)
```

** For the additional question in the edit**
Is that what you expect ?

```
> d1 <- c("e", "c", "a")
> d2 <- c("e", "a", "b")
> 
> w <- ifelse((d1 == "e") & (d2 == "e"), 1, 
+    ifelse((d1=="a") & (d2 == "b"), 2,
+    ifelse((d1 == "e"), 3, 99)))
>     
> data.frame(d1, d2, w)
  d1 d2  w
1  e  e  1
2  c  a 99
3  a  b  2
```

If you do not feel comfortable with the `ifelse` function, you can also work with the `if` and `else` statements for such applications.

Comment: Thanks a tonne, however the approach is only limited to 2 conditions? see the edited question above

Answer (score 4):

If you have a very limited number of levels, you could try converting `y` into factor and change its levels.

```
> xy <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 4), y = c(1, 4, 5))
> xy$w <- as.factor(xy$y)
> levels(xy$w) <- c("good", "fair", "bad")
> xy
  x y    w
1 1 1 good
2 2 4 fair
3 4 5  bad
```