# Create a New Column as per its Stages wrt Dates

Tags: r

I need to create a new column on the existing dataframe as "Project Status". 
This column should have records in it such as, SIR_Received stage, SIR_Approved stage, TSS_FC_Stage, TSS_Actual_stage, EP_Received stage, EP_Approved stage, Lease_Approved Stage, RFC_FC_Stage, 
RFC_Actual_stage & WIP.

The stages are in order so latest date should be captured in the Project_Status column ie, for example Row number 5 has dates till the column "EP_APP" so in prject_status column it shd be EP_Approved_Stage.

When there is date against "SIR_REC" column in the attached, it means its SIR_Received_stage 
similarly for all the dates and if all the columns are blank then the project status is WIP.

[image]

The new column should appear like this in the dataframe highlighted in RED.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Over the past weekend, this exact question with exactly this dataset has been reposted without a minimal reproducible example. [Please read the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In addition, [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125980/how-to-create-a-new-variable-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-condition) have been asked and [lots of information](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when) can be found on the internet on [how to do this](http://jenrichmond.rbind.io/post/mutate-and-if-else-to-create-new-variables/).

for your code you might want to look into `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(Project_status = case_when(
           !is.na(RFC_ACT) ~ "RFC_Actual_stage",
           !is.na(RFC_FC) ~ "RFC_???",
           !is.na(LEASE_APP) ~ "???",
           !is.na(EP_APP) ~ "???",
           !is.na(EP_REC) ~ "EP_Received_stage",
           !is.na(TSS_ACT) ~ "TSS_Actual_stage",
           !is.na(TSS_FC) ~ "TSS_???_stage",
           !is.na(SIR_App) ~ "SIR_Approved stage",
           !Is.na(SIR_REC) ~ "SIR_Received_Stage",
           TRUE ~ "WIP")
```

The mutate creates a new column named Project_status. Using the case_when you can determine the coditions on how this column should be filled. I assumed that WIP would be the last filled column so if that is not missing you want to use that one. Otherwise you want to use the column before last, if that is missing the column before that etc etc. The exact order in the case_when depends on the order you want. As you did not provide examples what should be in the Project_status column for all the columns, I just used ???. You can change that.

Comment: Hi Annet, Thanks much for the response. Pardon me i as i am learning how to get used to this, i might learn eventually with the right support.  I need to capture the latest column which has a date ie, if SIR_APP & SIR_REC both has dates then the Project_Status column should appear as SIR_Approved_Stage.

Comment: @Cyp so basically what you state here is condition. Project_status should be SIR_Approved_Stage when SIR_APP & SIR_REC are not missing. Which translates to `!is.na(SIR_APP) & !Is.na(SIR_REC) ~ SIR_Approved_Stage`. Start by writing out your conditions in words like I did in that sentence, it will make it easier to translate to R code.

Comment: No, i mean to tell if there are dates against both the columns SIR_REC & SIR_APP. The latest column out of this both should appear in the project status column ie SIR_Approved_stage.

Comment: In th attached excel see row number 5, There are dates in the first 5 columns till EP_APP so in the project status it should be EP_Approved stage ( thats the latest stage )

Comment: @Cyp I changed my answer, again provide a reprodicible example from the beginning and also please read the sources I provided. It was just a minor change in the code.

Comment: fs_d1$ps <-  ifelse(!is.na(fs_d1$RFC_ACT.1),"RFC_A", ifelse(!is.na(fs_d1$EP_APP.1), "EP_A", 
ifelse(!is.na(fs_d1$EP_REC.1),"EP_Rec",                     ifelse(!is.na(fs_d1$TSS_ACT.1), "TSS_A",
ifelse(!is.na(fs_d1$SIR_APPROVED.1),"SIR_App", ifelse(!is.na(fs_d1$SIR_RECEIVED.1), "SIR_Rec", "WIP"))))))                                         I was trying the wrong order all this while, i should have followed the reverse order like above. Seeing ur code, i could make sense but i am using a old version so dont have access to %>%. Thanks much.

Comment: @Cyp the %>% is pipeline from dplyr. It is a great package for reproducible code. Also, please please please do not use ifelse in ifelse in ifelse. Ik now it is functional, but it is very hard to read / unreprodicible. You can use exactly the same code but than with case_when, which is way more readable.

Comment: I always thought `%>%` was from the magrittr package. Maybe I'm wrong though. >.<

Comment: @Edward it definitely is in the magritrr package However, when I do `library(tidyverse)` or `library(dplyr)` I can use `%>%` but I cannot use `extract2`. The last one being a magritrr specific function, from which I assumed that package was not loaded with tidyverse. So I just assumed the pipeline thing occurs both in dplyr and magritrr. Edit: you are correct " let’s introduce the pipe operator: %>%. dplyr imports this operator from another package (magrittr)", probably this is the only thing from magrittr it imports than?